# How to make all interactions before using glmnet

Tags: r, formula, interaction, glmnet

I have an x-matrix of 8 columns. I want to run `glmnet` to do a lasso regression. I know I need to call:

```
glmnet(x, y, family = "binomial", ...).
```

However, how do I get `x` to consider all one way interactions as well? Do I have to manually remake the data frame: if so, is there an easier way? I suppose I was hoping to do something using an R formula.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes, there is a convenient way for that. Two steps in it are important.

```
library(glmnet)
# Sample data
data <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(9 * 10), ncol = 9))
names(data) <- c(paste0("x", 1:8), "y")
# First step: using .*. for all interactions
f <- as.formula(y ~ .*.)
y <- data$y
# Second step: using model.matrix to take advantage of f
x <- model.matrix(f, data)[, -1]
glmnet(x, y)
```

Comment: [, -1] 

is to remove an 'intercept' column that is auto created using model.matrix in this example.

Comment: is it possible to do this with caret? When I feed the model matrix into caret train with same settings it doesn't run the interaction variables

Comment: @KillerSnail, try `f <- as.formula( ~ .*.)` and `x <- model.matrix(f, TrainData)[, -1]` and then take `train(x = x, ...)`.

Comment: @RobertKubrick even though glmnet scales them before estimating?

Comment: Is there an easy way to multiply column 1 by columns 2:10?

Comment: @Dave, `x[, 1] * x[, 2:10]` does what you said; if you have something else in mind you should post a question.

Comment: I think this doesn't include quadratic terms? I.e. self-interactions.

Answer (score 3):

`f <- as.formula( ~ .^2)` should also work for including main effects and all pairwise interactions